# How to split dataset and cross-validate in Surprise?

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, cross-validation, recommendation-engine, train-test-split

I wrote the following code below which works:

```
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate

cross_validate(algo,dataset,measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'],cv=5, verbose=False, n_jobs=-1)
```

However when I do this: (notice the trainset is passed here in cross_validate instead of whole dataset)

```
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split
trainset, testset = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=test_size)
cross_validate(algo, trainset, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'],cv=5, verbose=False, n_jobs=-1)
```

It gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Trainset' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'
```

I looked it up and 
[Surprise documentation](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trainset.html) says that Trainset objects are not the same as dataset objects, which makes sense.

However, the documentation does not say how to convert the trainset to dataset.

My question is:
1. Is it possible to convert Surprise Trainset to surprise Dataset?
2. If not, what is the correct way to train-test split the whole dataset and cross-validate?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `trainset` is not for cross-validation. `Dataset` is for cross-validation. if you print your dataset `print(dataset)`, it will give:

```
<surprise.dataset.DatasetAutoFolds object at 0x7fe7fc06cd50>
```

which has already been configured for auto cross-validation.

The `trainset` which you got from `train_test_split` is not for cross-validation. You have to run the `.fit` method.

```
algo.fit(trainset)
```

If you want to use cross-validation on your `trainset`, I believe you have to do a `train_test_split` (through sklearn?) on your raw data, before you use the `reader` to convert them.